# Can't fix the hashtag in my angularjs app path

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tomcat

I know you guys are going to say "It's duplicated" but it doesn't work for me.

I'm doing exactly the same thing and here's what happens.

This is my config code:

```
portfolioApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            controller: 'portfolioController',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.htm'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
    if(window.history && window.history.pushState){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }

});
```

The URL without the locationProvider and setting path to "/" instead of "/home" would be:

```
http://localhost:8080/portfolio/#/
```

Okey, i would like to remove the hashtag and the "portfolio" path so that way it would be:

```
http://localhost:8080/home
```

With the config i've posted, it does it (the first time i refresh). But what happens? happens that if I refresh the page again with the new path... i get a 404 Tomcat Error.

In the first refresh when i write localhost:8080/portfolio and the path gets converted into "/home", I get in the console an error saying that the "partials/home.htm" can't be found 404.

So either way, it can't read my partial, and then when I refresh everything is broken.

How can I solve this? what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your including these to scripts in the header of your HTML document Where you are implementing your module. The two provided below are for implementing the most current version of angular as well as the most current version of the angular route script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular-route.js"></script>
```

Make sure your injecting ngRoute into your module, here's an example of mine:

```
angular.module('controller', ['ngRoute','ngResource', 'ngCookies', 'ngSanitize'])
```

Here is an example of my config block, make sure you inject both routeProvider and locationProvider:

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '../partials/member.php',
            controller: 'Member',
            access: 'member'
        })
        .when('/leaderboard', {
            templateUrl: '../partials/leaderboard.html',
            controller: 'Leaderboard',
            access: 'member'
        })
        .otherwise({ 
            redirectTo: '/' 
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}])
```

If your doing all of this and it still doesn't work post a plunker of your code. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, i'm actually using angular.min.js, don't think that would be a problem right? going to check the rest and let you know :) question, why would I need Sanitize? i've only used it once for my web re-rendering.

Comment: I got it exactly the way you have, obviously taking out the things i don't need, i only need the ngRoute injected in the module. Then in the controller i add the routeProvider and locationProvider. In the config path i got "/" for the when and otherwise as well. Now the URL is "localhost:8080" without "/home". :(

Comment: when i remove the Html5Mode thing, it works... but the path would still not work... did exactly the same thing :(

Comment: You need the html5 line, did you add the route script tag in your header below your angular script tag. Also use the full angular script tag now, it will also give you more specific errors in your console.

Comment: what happens when you go to /test